# how to pass dynamically text at pseudo class in tailwind css - after:content-[?] in react js inside .map

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, tailwind-css

By hovering at the text ::after pseudo-class content is going to be visible, but by just looking or testing, I wouldn't print that text content in the browser by this approach in tailwind-css with react-js inside .map()

```
const data = [
    "Web Design",
    "Development",
    "Illustration",
    "Product Design",
    "Social Media",
];
```

```
<ul className='flex flex-col gap-5 text-[85px]'>
{
  data.map(item =>
    <li
      key={item}
      className={`cursor-pointer relative
      after:content-['${item}']  <----- this approach is not working...! Why?
      after:absolute
      after:right-0
      after:text-red-200 `}
    >

      {item}

    </li>
  )
}
</ul>
```

though I try this approach also...

```
after:content-[${item}]
```

Answer (score 8):

after more R&D find a way to pass dynamic data as value to (::after) pseudo-class in tailwind css

```
<ul className='flex flex-col gap-5 text-[85px]'>
{
  data.map(item =>
    <li
      key={item}
      after-dynamic-value={item}
      className={`cursor-pointer relative
      after:content-[attr(after-dynamic-value)]  <----- this approach is working...
      after:absolute
      after:right-0
      after:text-red-200 `}
    >

      {item}

    </li>
  )
}
</ul>
```